Martial arts movie about an evil assassin with inhuman powers using a small ring as a weapon
There is a kung fu movie I saw only a couple of scenes as kid. It should have been released between 1990 and 1998. The movie plot is setup in a present world (or whatever was present in the 90ties). The main character plays two clones/twins - one evil assassin and a good one. He is a tall skinny Asian guy. In my memory he looks like Mark Dacascos. 
As far as I know, the good clone struggles to discover his true powers or he is injured somehow. He is hiding from his evil twin. 
The assassin wears a black suit. He has immense powers. He seems not even human. Shows little emotions. In one scene at some office the assassin kills a guy, who has no clue, who he is dealing with, with a tiny shuriken or even just a small sharp metal ring which he shoots only with his fingers. I believe he uses this weapon a couple of times.
The movie is not "The One" with Jet Lee
Update: 
It turned out, the protagonists were not twins.

What is the country of origin and language of the film?

i guess it's a us film in english. But i don't know exactly, because as i saw it, i was living in russia and it was a pirated copy with one voice translation

Here's me reading this question: "The One?... Sounds like The One... Yep, definitely The One... Oh." :/

Did a african american guy accompany the good guy in this movie? And the movies final fight took place in a club or restaurant i think , was it like this?

Sry i have no clue how it ends. Thats why i want to watch it, saw only as kid couple of scenes in on cable tv. Probably had to go to bed in between (:. But i will defenetely recognize it when i See it. Trying to look it up every now and then for years. Plz if you have a guess, just post, not going to downvote

Could be Tai Chi alias Twin Warriors: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108281/

Or maybe Gemini: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0210302/

unfortunately not, it was not set up in this samurai or shaolin past world. The plot is in some present western country.

lol, @Hitman2847, i think you're right with your guess. There are no twins at all in the movie. And Mark Dacascos is indeed playing in it. Post your answer, i'm gonna upvote

I think you mean Drive. There is no twins in it but I remember this is what looks like what you explained with Mark Dacascos playing in it.
